# Show only a count of the unhandled flags in the top bar

Tags: feature-request, flagging, 10k-tools

Since the change in the formatting of the top bar, I get a yellow box with a number in it containing the number of flags that need to reviewed. I click on it to take me to the flag review page. This is useful.

However, after I've voted on the flags, the number doesn't change -- I have no way of knowing whether there are new flags that need to be handled, or if clicking on the box will just take me to an empty page. Instead of the number of outstanding flags, including the ones I have already voted on (a number that is useful mostly for moderators, I suppose?) I propose that the box instead show the number of outstanding flags that I have *not* yet voted on.